# Jmeter- Read all the files from a folder and based on file type perform the validation

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have different types of csv files Company, Jobcode, Workforce which I will be dropping in SFTP and file will be processed and saved in DB. I need to compare and validate the values of csv files and DB values so that all the records are saved correctly.

For a single file, I have followed the below steps and was able to verify.

1. Thread Group 1 --> Drop a single file to SFTP and get the number of lines in Beanshell post processor
2. Thread Group 2 --> JDBC Request and  Loop controller- csv file config and JSSR sampler to loop for each value of csv and compare with DB value

Dropping Multiple Files
(i). Beanshell processor - To read files from Folder and storing in a variable-file and passing this variable (file) to -> ForEachController and placed the SFTP sampler to process files(so that records will be saved in DB).

To validate the csv file and DB values, I need to get the csv line count of each file for which I am writing all the read files from folder in step (i) to another csv file (named as `Allfiles.csv`). Now the problem is "Allfiles.csv" has the below content

```
C:\Users\AllFiles\Company_V1_0_201712251403.txt
C:\Users\AllFiles\JobCode_V1_0_201712040436.txt
C:\Users\AllFiles\Workc_V1_0_201802081914.txt
```

Since is backslash(), I had replaced it with forward slash (//) and saved in variable.

Now I need to get the line numbers of each file.

I have used Loop Controller-> CSV data config and JSSR Sampler which has below code

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils
import java.io.*

csvLineContent = vars.get('AllFiles')
log.info("-------------->" + csvLineContent)

csvLineContent = csvLineContent.replace('\\', '//') //replacing slash
vars.put('csvLineContent', csvLineContent)
log.info("==============" + csvLineContent)
csvfileWithoutExt = FilenameUtils.getName(csvLineContent)
log.info("File name is " + csvfileWithoutExt) //Get only file name

try {
    if (csvfileWithoutExt.startsWith("C")) //Get the line count for company file
    {
        log.info("File Name of Company file-------> " + csvfileWithoutExt)
        log.info("File full path ---> " + csvLineContent)
        reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader('csvLineContent')) // Issue here
        log.info("Reading file ====" + reader)
     }
} catch (Throwable ex) {
     log.error("Error in Beanshell", ex);
     throw ex;
}
```

I am not able to get the line number of each file.

```
2018-08-22 22:06:14,583 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Error in Beanshell
java.io.FileNotFoundException: csvLineContent (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are reading file name, to read file by variable context remove the quotes surronding variable name:

```
 reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(csvLineContent))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to change this line:

   ```
   reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader('csvLineContent'))
   ```

   to this one:

   ```
   reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(csvLineContent))
   ```

   however I don't think it gonna work as the files live under `C:\Users\AllFiles` folder and in order to read it you need to provide the full path, not only the name
2. As per [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) users are recommended to user JSR223 Test Elements and **Groovy** language, if you use `beanshell` language in the JSR223 elements - you will not have any performance improvements
3. Counting lines in file in Groovy is as simple as:

   ```
   int linesNo = new File('csvLineContent').readLines().size()
   ```

   More information:

   - [Groovy JDK Enhancements](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/)
   - [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)